# Apache or php prepends \n character application wide

Tags: php, apache, opensuse

So I'm really stuck on this.

I've had a hardware failure a while back on the production environment and had to use the backup. However, ever since then I've been getting this \n problem and it's driving me insane.

It seems to be present application wide. My XHR responses look like:

```
1.
2. <<Normal xhr stuff>>
```

instead of

```
1. <<Normal xhr stuff>>
```

Csv exports:

```
1. 
2. <<Expected export data>>
```

instead of

```
1. <<Expected export data>>
```

Even js functions are affected by this. I send "-1" from the backend and expect "-1" in a js variable, instead I end up with "\n-1" completely screwing up my logic and generating unexpected behavior.

Weirdest thing is that this does not happen on the test environment, although sources are identical and php.ini / other seemingly relevant config files are similar as well.

Apache versions is 2.2 while PHP is 5.1.4 running on an openSUSE10 OS.

Comment: And what do you expect from us now? We know _nothing_ about your script/server internals, so we have even less chance of successfully debugging this than you.

Comment: I'm hoping it's somewhat of a more common problem. Something someone with more server-side knowledge than me would have a hunch on / has experienced before.

It's not something I've ever encountered before so really any thread to follow is worth it.